# How do i compile nfsutils for MIPS architecture?

Tags: c, debugging, mips, nfs

I need to run an nfsclient on a MIPS target machine, and nfsserver on an x86 machine. Tried to google, but couldn't find an exact solution. Can someone help me with how to compile nfs-utils with MIPS as target?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but perhaps you could use http://mira.sunsite.utk.edu/eldk/4.1/mips-linux-x86/distribution/mips_4KC/RPMS/nfs-utils-mips_4KC-1.0.7-12_3.mips.rpm

It must be possible if mips linux can do it.